# Jsp и Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

Можно ли в Jsp использовать Hibernate  для быстрого подключения к базе данных? Или их лучше не смешивать?

Comment: JSP - это только представлении. Логики в нем быть не должно. Просто вынесите работу с БД в отдельный класс. И пользуйтесь в нем Hibernate-ом.

Comment: Можно, но лучше этого не делать. JSP на самом деле - это как бы сервлет, вывернутый наизнанку. И всегда компилируется сервером приложений в самый настоящий сервлет. Таким образом с технической точки зрения может быть чем угодно, в том числе и представлением и преславутой логикой. Просто совершенно справедливо решили, что смешивать html и программный код плохо и JSP отводят только роль представления. Тем самым программа разбивается на логические участки, которые легко поддерживать даже независимо друг от друга. И заменять такие блоки, не трогая остальные. В общем сразу много всего хорошего.

Comment: Сергей вы совтуете отказаться от Hibernate -а использовать jsp для подключения к бд  способом mvc ???

Comment: я вас правльно понел

Comment: Нет. Не правильно.

Comment: Совтуете использовать Хибернайт для подключения к БД jsp для Обработки этих данных тоесть для логики  ,так правьнее??

Comment: Какие цели преследуете? Пойти путём, который сейчас считается правильным или просто по-быстренькому посмотреть hibernate с jsp? Чтобы сделать всё "правельно" одних Hibernate и JSP недостаточно. Хотите сделать MVC? Тогда JSP - это представление. M пусть будет база/hibernate (хотя не совсем так, но пусть) Осталось C что будет в качестве С? Кто будет подключаться к базе (через jdbc или через hibernate совершенно неважно), выполнять логику?

Comment: Следует освоить какой-нибудь фреймвёрк MVC. Очень популярный spring framework. Главный конкурент JSF. Это всё серьёзные сложные вещи. Быстрый результат не гарантирован. Если нет желания заниматься этой мурой, то делайте всё в JSP, но помните, что все скажут "это плохо".

Comment: Не возможно отказаться от Hibernate и тем самым прийти к mvc. Эти вещи ну никак не связаны между собой, не заменяют друг-друга. Смешение hibernate c jsp не хуже и не лучше смешения с jsp того же jdbc или любого другого кода на java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смешивать безусловно можно, вопрос стоит ли. Если нужно именно jsp и хочется использовать hibernate, то можно для работы с базой данных вынести логику работы с базой в session beans, которые в свою очередь логично использовать в jsp. Но естественно никто не запрещает создавать hibenate сессию прямо в jsp и там всю логику оставить.